# Facebook graph API manual login flow in iOS returns error_reason user_denied

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ios7, facebook-login

I'm trying to create manual Facebook login in iOS using UIWebView for the login flow
for learning propose. I know there is framework for this.
Any way I'm starting with :

1. First 
   https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=80xxxxx03174&redirect_uri=http://www.
   facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&scope=user_friends&response_type=token&display=
   touch
2. Redirects me to :
   https://m.facebook.com/v2.0/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%
   2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html&scope=user_friends&response_type=token&client_id=
   80xxxxx03174
3. Redirects me again to error
   https://m.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=8072xxxx03174&signed_next=1&
   next=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fv2.0%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%
   252Fwww.facebook.com%252Fconnect%252Flogin_success.html%26scope%3Duser_friends%
   26response_type%3Dtoken%26client_id%3D8072922xxx174%26ret%3Dlogin&cancel_uri=http%3A%2F%
   2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html%3Ferror%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%
   3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%23_%3D_&
   display=touch&_rdr

Now the user and the app do exists.
I tested the first ( no'1 ) URL in the browser and it returns me the access_token back

**UPDATE:**
I found out the number 3 request is invoking twice and in the first time I present the WebView and then in the second time it sends this. I try to present the same web view that is already presented and I got exception.
So way do this request send it self twice?